# Unable to deploy HoloLens application

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, hololens, hololens-emulator

### My setup

#### HoloLens

- Windows version   14393.576.x86fre.rs1_release_inmarket.161208-2252

#### Desktop

- Windows 10 Pro 14393.576
- Visual Studio Community 2015 Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3 (all products installed)

### The Problem

I am unable to deploy any application to the HoloLens, or the emulator's either (which I'm not as concerned about, Hyper-V works but the emulators freeze every time). I'm attempting with the Origami application exported from Unity as in the tutorial. I'm able to login through the [device portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CA0hN.jpg) easily enough as I have developer mode on. Visual Studio does auto-detect the device as a remote machine. But when you attempt to deploy it, I always get the same DEP0100 error, that the device is not in developer mode. I'm at a loss for what else to try, or what setting I've missed. I've reset the HoloLens several times and reinstalled Visual Studio only to get the same thing. One thing that concerns me is during the autodetect, it says the device has [no developer license](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m99yM.jpg). My company definitely paid for the developer edition, so it should be, but that's the only clue I have for why this refuses to work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried pairing your machine and your HoloLens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work today. After using our company's other device, and it working smoothly, I noticed that there was a mismatch between the sdk version on the dev machine and what the HoloLens was currently upgraded to. I had updated the device to the latest Windows updates, and it made it not work with either of the sdk's that come out of the box with Visual Studio 2015. It wasn't very intuitive problem, but I guess all of this is new. I'm just happy it's working now, and hope this helps anyone else who runs into this issue.

Comment: could you elaborate on how did you check the sdk version on both?

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable Developer mode on your Windows 10 machine and obtain a windows 10 developer license?

Comment: I do have developer mode enabled on my windows 10 machine, but I haven't seen anything about needing a developer license. How do I go about getting one?

Comment: For me Visual Studio forced me through the workflow of getting one the first time I opened a UWP project.  It looks like if you open a UWP project (like a HoloLens one), you should have a Project -> Store -> Acquire Developer License menu item.