# Unable to deploy on HoloLens

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017, hololens, hololens-emulator

## **My setup**

### HoloLens

Windows 10 October 2018 Update (10.0.17763.134)

### Desktop

Windows 10 Enterprise
Visual Studio Community 2017 Version
Unity 2018.2.19f1 (Latest 7th December 2018 Update)

### The Problem

I am unable to deploy any application to the HoloLens, but able to deploy it on hololens-emulator. I'm attempting with the Origami application exported from Unity as in the tutorial. I'm able to pair with the HoloLens easily and I have developer mode on. Visual Studio also does auto-detect the device as a remote machine. But when I attempt to deploy it, I always get the same "DEP0100" error, that the device is not in developer mode though the device is already in a developer mode. I'm at a loss for what else to try, or what setting I've missed. I've reset the HoloLens several times and reinstalled Visual Studio only to get the same thing.

I have already tried the solution mentioned here [Unable to deploy HoloLens application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41368583/unable-to-deploy-hololens-application][1]) but it didn't work for me.

Comment: I'm sorry that you face those issues but I'm afraid StackOverflow is not quite the correct address for this. Maybe you should try it directly at the [Windows Mixed reality developer support and community - Windows Dev Center](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/community). since it works with the emulator I'ld say this question is not Unity related. However you say you tried the solutions from the related question .. so you are sure your Windows SDK versions are now all up-to-date?

Comment: I have some confusion, I updated one of the SDK version but are there more than one SDK versions which need to be updated as you are mentioning all SDK versions are up-to-date?

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what you got. But I have couple ideas:

1. You connected to HL as Remote Machine, but HL is Device.
2. You built an appx as x64, but HL is x86.
3. You didn't install a proper runtime, debug or release.
4. You use older SDK than HL platform version.
5. You minimal target platform is higher then HL platform version.

Maybe something else. You need to investigate the Hololens logs. Open "Windows Device Portal"/System/Logging.

Then you need to select some providers with severity by choosing them in box and clicking "Enable". I usually begin from "Microsoft-Windows-WinRT-Error" ETW provider.

DO NOT CLOSE THE LOGGING PAGE!!!!!

Start the debugger with app, see the error and go to Logging page. Try to find out the root of issue.